# UBCD built for Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, windows-pe, ubcd

UBCD4Win is a great tool, but I still prefer the Windows 7 interface much better. As well, it'd be nice to have up to date tools instead of older tools available, plus it'd be nice to run off of a USB drive.

Is there a version or an alternative tool that uses the Windows 7 PE Environment? Or something that could integrate with the Startup Repair section that I can put onto a USB drive?

Tools that would help:

1. Hard disk drive checking tool (HDTune and CHKDSK)
2. Network Access (with a basic web browser, and SMB/FTP share browser)
3. Hardware diagnostic
4. Memory Tester (Yes, I know one is built in...)
5. Password reset tools
6. Keyfinders
7. Imaging across a network / to a separate drive
8. More AV tools
9. A real GUI (Windows Explorer)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're looking for is called MSDaRT. It comes in both 32bit and 64 bit Flavors. MSDaRT8 is out now, and now includes an option for remote desktop FROM the boot disc. If you're running Win7, you can only build DaRT7 discs, and if you're on Win8, you can only build DaRT8 Discs.

The microsoft diagnostics and repair toolset is based on Windows PE and it performs diagnostic and recovery on an offline copy of Windows. It can manage files, edit Windows Registry, uninstall previously installed Windows updates, scan system for malware and restore deleted files.

[image: MSDaRT]

It's however only available to Volume Liscence Users or TechNet Subscribers as part of the Microsoft Desktop Optimization Pack.

> Microsoft Diagnostics and Recovery Toolset (MSDaRT) 6.5 helps diagnose and repair a system that has trouble starting or has other issues. When you start the system using the Emergency Repair Disk (ERD), also referred to as Boot CD for MSDaRT, a System Recovery Options dialog box appears. A graphical environment and a command-line console are available. The command-line console can be opened by clicking the Command Prompt option in the System Recovery Options menu. You can access any Windows® 7 or Windows Server® 2008 R2 file system, which includes FAT, FAT32, and NTFS. Microsoft Diagnostics and Recovery Toolset is available on the System Recovery Options menu. Clicking MSDaRT opens a detailed MSDaRT Tools menu which presents various recovery tools.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee460909.aspx

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/enterprise/products-and-technologies/mdop/dart.aspx

Comment: So otherwise, no legal way to access that?

Comment: Technet Subscription's not terribly expensive. I split the cost with a buddy of mine.